# What does SootMethod.getSubSignature() meaning?

Tags: java, soot

In many java project which using Soot, I see the `SootMethod.getSubSignature()`.

I know that we have `SootMethod.Signature()` for getting signature of method but what does `SootMethod.getSubSignature()` meaning.

what is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Eric said I examine these methods on one Soot Method and I find the answer.Consider we have a method named Test which is defined in SignTest class and has int return type and no input argument. when we call test.getSignature() the answer which is returned

```
<Sigtest: int Test()>
```

and when we call test.getSubSignature()

```
int Test()
```

So the difference between these to method is in subsignature we don't mention the method's relevant class.

Answer (score 1):

Just print the two to the command line then you will see.